# Working on an iOS project as a team and defining access to team members

Tags: ios, git

I searched all over the web but all i can see is Git! Maybe i got it all wrong but what i am looking for is a mechanism for creating a complete development team for my iOS app project. It should consist of a two team managers and team members. Each team member would get access to a limited number of files and resources and the team managers can overview and modify the changes made to the project by the members. I am sure part of this is done through Gits but how do i handle the access definition and team work part with Git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have access to a server on which you can define bare repos:

- the lightweight tool for fine-grained access control level is [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html) (perl, with lots of [access rules](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/conf.html#rules), no database required)
- the more complete solution would be [GitLab CE](https://about.gitlab.com/features/) (Git repo hosting in ruby, with a [large permission matrix](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/permissions/permissions.md))
- or, more recently: [Gogs](http://gogs.io/) (Git repo hosting in [Go](https://golang.org/))

The last two work with a database for user definition.